# What is the difference between APSA and APSB?

Tags: patching

What would be the difference between Adobe APSA and APSB security bulletins / advisories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Adobe Product Security Bulletin (APSB):** An announcement about a security vulnerability in an Adobe product. The ***vulnerability has been patched***, and the solution is to update to a newer version of the product.
- **Adobe Product Security Advisory (APSA):** Same as APSB, except that the ***vulnerability has not been patched yet***, and a fix update isn't available yet. A solution is either to downgrade to a safe version, using other mitigation methods, or that there's no current solution.